# Calling Python through BAT for Scheduled Task

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, bat

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 and setting up some scheduled tasks to run on our server.
I am calling a python script in a .bat file.

When  it runs, the connection to our SDE database is "invalid" or do not exist/supported.

However, if I open ArcCatalog and connect to our SDE it runs without a hitch.

In the script I have a few feature classes referenced as this:

```
Database Connections\\Connection to gisserver.sde\\master.DBO.Blah\\master.DBO.Towns
```

And the SDE as :

```
masterSDE = "Database Connections\\Connection to gisserver.sde"
```

I want this script to be automated overnight, so opening up ArcCatalog is not an option.

Is there  a way to establish a connection to databases (SDE's) like you would in ArcCatalog programmatically?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to be sure the SDE connection file you want to use is accessible by the user running the script, on the machine running the script.

"Database Connections" is a shortcut to a folder under the current user profile, e.g.: `%APPDATA%\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcCatalog`. You do NOT have to use this shortcut! You can just as easily specify the full path to the file. You can put the file anywhere, but I would recommend a secure network location that only the appropriate users can access.

If you want to create the SDE connection file programmatically you can use the [Create Database Connection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Create_Database_Connection/00170000016q000000/) or [Create ArcSDE Connection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000pt000000) tools.

The main difference between these two tools is that the former is intended for direct (2-tier) connections to the database, while the latter is intended for application server (3-tier) connections through an ArcSDE service, although in practice you can use the latter for direct connections as well.